# Regression for dependent variable with 4 categories

Tags: logistic, sas

I want to do a regression where my dependent variable has four categories `(1,2,3,4)` which represents the number of dependents. Can I do this with logistic regression? I read somewhere that `link=glogit` option is useful in this, can somebody please shed some light? I am new to this.

Writing the syntax here would be very useful for me.

Comment: @ayush, I suspect that you need answers in R, if so, please add tag r. More context on the problem, sample data, would go long way in helping to get appropriate answer.

Comment: @mpiktas -- sorry,I need answers in SAS..Basically I had too many missing values in customer number of dependents so I am left with making a mini model with few relevant predictors to predict the number of dependents..These number of dependents can be 1,2,3 or 4. Therefore I need a regression method which has Dependent variable with more than 2 categories which happens in normal logistic regression. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @ayush, added sas tag, sorry I myself never used sas, so I cannot help, but maybe someone can give some reasonable answer.

Comment: anybody with sas experience please.

Comment: @ayush When you say "dependents", do you mean like "this person has five dependent children".  If so, what happens if someone has 0 or 5 dependents?

Comment: @jeromy -- dependents could be any one. Not specified anywhere that children could be the only dependents.

Comment: @ayush I didn't mean to say that dependents could only be children. I understand that dependents can be a spouse, a parent, a grandparent, or anyone. My point is, what happens if someone has 0 or 5 dependents? At present your dependent variable sounds like a count variable as opposed to a categorical variable with four levels. This may have implications for modelling.

Comment: @jeromy -- apologies for late reply. The datamart doesnt have case in which 0 or 5 dependent is the case..Not sure if missing value means one of those. We only have dependents from 1 to 4. I agree that this may have implications in modeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look up the literature on multinomial logistic regression, a.k.a. nominal regression.  It's an expanded version of the usual logistic regression.  Coefficients and odds ratios obtained deal with the likelihood of the outcome being A, B, or C *as opposed to D*, the reference category.  Thus for 4 levels of a dependent variable you'll have 3 tables with coefficients, odds ratios, etc.  You'll want to make sure you choose that reference category intentionally:  to which result will you and your readers most want to make comparisons?  Sorry I can't provide syntax but SAS documentation should be a help there.

Comment: With an ordered outcome you porobaly don't want to do nominal regression.

Comment: Good point, Aniko, I missed that it was ordinal.  @ayush - a quick google search on 'SAS "ordinal regression"' turns up a lot of info.

Answer (score 2):

I think this document: [logistic](http://www.biostat.umn.edu/~melanie/PH7402/2009/NOTE/logistic.pdf) holds all the information you need (with pointers to how you can do it in both R and SAS). It explains the concept of the proportional odds model and indicates that glogit is indeed the way to go.

If you need more, just google for "SAS proportional odds logistic regression"...

Answer (score 2):

If you need imputation (as your comment suggests), look into `PROC MI`. It is specifically designed for this purpose. One of the many options it has is imputation of an ordinal outcome.

For example, the following code will use proportional odds regression to impute `ndependents` based on `x1`, `x2` and their interaction.

```
proc mi;
   class ndependents;
   var x1 x2;
   monotone logistic(ndependents= x1 x2 x1*x2);
run;
```

You can do only one imputation, but multiple imputations are preferrable. After the analysis you can use `PROC MIANALYZE` to combine the results.

Comment: thanks. Though I fear that Proc Mi has notoriety for not dealing well with big datasets. My dataset has 12 lakh rows. Any views ?

Comment: I would go ahead and try it before worrying.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to you to consider using decision trees (such as CART) for such problems.
I see that SAS Enterprise Miner has some functions for decision trees:

http://sas-x.com/2011/01/decision-trees-in-sas-enterprise-miner-and-spss-clementine/

Comment: Thanks . With decision trees you get the rule based classification which gives you the probable indicators of the event. I already have indicators with me. I want a sas syntax so that I can use those classifiers for 4 categories and score my dataset.